# Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession,

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

[Error Msg[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNOYX.png)

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, instance of __PHP_Incomplete_Class given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\FB\download_album.php on line 67 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\FB\libs\Facebook\FacebookRequest.php on line 182`strong text

```
if ( isset( $_GET['all_albums'] ) && !empty ( $_GET['all_albums'] ) ) {
    if ( $_GET['all_albums'] == 'all_albums' ) {

        require_once('libs/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
        // graph api request for user data
        $request_albums = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/albums?fields=id,name');
        $response_albums = $request_albums->execute();

        // get response
        $albums = $response_albums->getGraphObject()->asArray();

        if ( !empty( $albums ) ) {
            foreach ( $albums['data'] as $album ) {
                $album = (array) $album;
                download_album( $session, $album_download_directory, $album['id'], $album['name'] );
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: So, what is `$session` in your code …?

Comment: It does not look like you set `$session` to anything

Comment: Please dont post pictures of code. Post the code as text into your question and format it according to [the docs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: $session = $_SESSION['fb_login_session'];

Comment: session is the fb_login session!

Comment: $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
I am putting this value into $session!

Comment: PHP can not de-serialize this properly again when the session is picked up, because you only require the `FacebookSession.php` script file much later … that’s what “instance of __PHP_Incomplete_Class” means. You need to embed the script file before the session is picked up again. You should really use the autoloader script that comes with the SDK, rather than requiring individual script files later on.

Comment: @misorude i thought that beofore!
Could you please guide me, how can i add autoloader script in this?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk#usage